# Use lmer to test main effects and interaction

Tags: r, mixed-model, p-value, lme4-nlme

I have to solve a problem using a linear mixed model (`lmer`). Six subjects performed two tests, (`test1`, `test2`) in two different locations (`on holiday`, `at work`). These are my data:

```
subj     <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6)
location <- c("holiday","holiday","holiday","holiday","holiday","holiday", 
              "work","work","work","work","work","work")
test     <- c("test1", "test2","test1", "test2","test1", "test2","test1", 
              "test2","test1", "test2","test1", "test2") 
value    <- c(56,32,89,32,56,34,23,98,32,120,41,67)
data     <- data.frame(subj, location, test, value)
```

Using `lmer`, I have to verify if there is an effect of the variable `location`, if there is an effect of the variable `test`, and if there is an interaction, `location X test`.

I thought a model like this might be appropriate:

```
lmer(value ~ location*test + (1|subj))
```

Could it work?

Furthermore, I have to verify if there is a difference between `holiday.test1` and `work.test1`, and between `holiday.test2` and `work.test2`. I also need p-values.

[image: boxplot(value ~ location*test)]

Comment: *It could work* but I think your dataset having essentially two data-points per subject, is too small to estimate robust standard deviations for your random effects. I think simply using a `lm` would greatly simplify your life and provide you with the same inferential insights. Finally giving the really small dataset you are having I wouldn't trust asymptotic tests for $p$-values. I would strongly suggest using `lme4`'s native `bootMer()` function to bootstrap your model and get parametric bootstrap estimates (If you really want a LME model that is).

Comment: What about creating two models:<Br>`fm1 = lmer(value ~ test*location + (1|sub), data=tot)` and `fm2 = lmer(value ~ test+location + (1|sub), data=tot)` and using an `anova(fm1,fm2)`. In this case I could say: there is(or not) an interaction `test X location`. Then I could creating two models:`fm3 = lmer(value ~ test+location + (1|sub), data=tot)`
and `fm4 = lmer(value ~ test + (1|sub), data=tot)` and verify if `location` affects value... it's correct? I'm a bit confused:)

Comment: I think you are describing backwards elimination here... This is OK given you understand some important caveats about data-dredging  (which is a bad thing - see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection) :) What I said in my earlier comment still applies. 1. Get more data, or get a simpler model. 2. Use bootstrap to get your $p$-values. Asymptotic tests work for large samples and you appear not to have one.